# ASP.NET AJAX returning XML when JSON specified

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webmethod

This is my first time using AJAX with ASP.NET so please allow m some rope.

I have a simple AJAX request that I wish to retuen a JSON string but ASP.NET keeps formatting the JSON string as XML

here is my code

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public string GetModels()
{
   string response;

   using (var context = new myDataModel())
   {
     var m = from model in context.ListModels select model;
     var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     response = serializer.Serialize(m);
   }

   return response;
}
```

this is called but returns an XML node containing my JSON string really confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my method for returning JSON from a webservice using ASP.NET

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetJSON()
    {

        DataTable dtMarkers = new DataTable();
        dtMarkers.Load(<<STORED PROCEDURE>>.GetReader());

        string[][] myArray = new string[dtMarkers.Rows.Count][];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow marker in dtMarkers.Rows)
        {
            myArray[i] = new string[] { marker["ID"].ToString(), marker["Title"].ToString(), marker["Blurb"].ToString(), marker["Url"].ToString(), marker["LongLatPoint"].ToString() };
            i++;
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string strJSON = js.Serialize(myArray);
        Context.Response.Clear();
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.Flush();
        Context.Response.Write(strJSON);

    }
```

this particular example reads Googlemaps pointers from a database and returns them to the ASP.NET page for displaying on an instance of Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it like:

```
public JsonResult GetModels()
{
    //.........

    return new JsonResult() { Data = new { result=response  } };
}
```

Comment: thanks Bjarki and simon, I have debugged the method and see that the JavaScriptSerializer is returning a json string, so I am assuming that it is the webmethod that is adding the xml data?